# PhoneGap on iOS with absolute path URLs for assets?

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview, cordova, sprockets

Porting a web app to phoneGap on iOS, we have asset (and ajax) URLs that are absolute paths, e.g.:

```
<img src="/img/logo.png">
```

We have the img directory packaged under PhoneGap's www directory.  The image will not load with the absolute path, but only with a relative path, e.g.:

```
<img src="img/logo.png">
```

Could someone please explain how the URL is being prefixed or translated in this context? I.e.:

```
<img src="/www/img/logo.png">
```

does not work either. So what is the URL base used by PhoneGap on iOS?

We've also tried, e.g.:

```
<img src="file://img/logo.png">
<img src="file:///img/logo.png">
```

but no go.

We would like to avoid changing the URLs to relative for the port, as absolute path URLs are used throughout the CSS, Ajax code, are set by Sprockets with the Rails backend, etc. How can we just get PhoneGap/UIWebView on iOS to load the assets using the absolute path URLs as written?

I see this question is asked a lot in various forms here on StackOverflow, but I've yet to see a correct answer.

Comment: Assuming it's a single-page app (as is generally recommended for PhoneGap/Cordova), any reason you can't just use <base href="."> in your index.html and call it a day?

Answer (score 17):

One can get the path to the application in JavaScript by:

```
cordova.file.applicationDirectory
```

Since I'm on Android, it says: "file:///android_asset/" ...for example:

```
var img_path = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/img/logo.png';
```

Like this all resources would be found when cross-building for various platforms.

Comment: The Cordova JS layer is all the same, no matter which platform. Please complain at the "Genius Bar" concerning your iOS issues, not exactly my fault.

Comment: It is a bug in Cordova, at least on 3.7 on iOS, as I explain in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905969/load-assets-from-www-folder-on-ios-8-with-cordova-3-7-file Btw I was not complaining, just  stating.

Comment: the current version is v4.0.0... maybe consider upgrading? could imagine that the objective C part not exposes it properly to the JS part. sorry for ranting.

Comment: I am on the latest release. Cordova versioning is confusing, as CLI 4.1.2 resolves to 3.7 on iOS and 3.6.4 on Android. A good post about it is http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

Comment: This works for me with iOS 8, believe it is the correct answer.

Comment: Works and needs the File plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: For starters, please mention that it needs https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file

Answer (score 8):

Did some testing and maybe a bit of JavaScript hackery can make it a bit more manageable. This will change all `<a>` and `<img>` tags with URL starting with / to be relative to the current file.

Put this into a file and include it with a `<script>` tag or inject it with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var dummy = document.createElement("a");
  dummy.setAttribute("href", ".");
  var baseURL = dummy.href;
  var absRE = /^\/(.*)$/;

  var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for (var i =  0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = images[i];
    var groups = absRE.exec(img.getAttribute("src"));
    if (groups == null) {
      continue;
    }

    img.src = baseURL + groups[1];
  }

  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i =  0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    var groups = absRE.exec(link.getAttribute("href"));
    if (groups == null) {
      continue;
    }

    link.href = baseURL + groups[1];
  }
});
```

Comment: hmm, well a nice approach but not sure the timing on that will work since it needs to modify the paths of all the other includes on the main page.  maybe better to hack PG to just delete the leading '/'... looking into that.

Comment: Yeah that might be a problem. But note that PhoneGap on iOS is more or less just a `UIWebView` too so you will end up with the same problems. I think you must rewrite the HTML code dynamically (template system?) and or also intercept link clicks somehow... i haven't figure out how. Let me know of your progress.

Comment: At this stage since it's only our own well-formed HTML, a simple sed script in the build pipeline did the trick, e.g. sed -e /href="\//href="/

Comment: The idea to use **sed** was awesome.  Much more reliable than something at runtime.  But instead of **sed** I made a cordova hook and used node with the [replace package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace).

Answer (score 3):

When checking the absolute path through your iPhone/iPad you would see something like this:

```
<img src="file:///var/mobile/Applications/7D6D107B-D9DC-479B-9E22-4847F0CA0C40/YourApplication.app/www/logo.png" />
```

And it will be different on `Android` or `Windows` devices so I don't think it's actually a good idea to reference assets using absolute paths in this case.

As an alternative you could consider using the `base64` strings in your CSS files:

```
div#overview
{
    background-image: url('data:image/jpeg;base64, <IMAGE_DATA>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: thanks. is there a PG API to cough up the current absolute path to the doc root?    we do use data urls for some images but it's not a universal solution.

Comment: `PhoneGap` has an exposed API for file manipulations, but I didn't have a chance to use it yet: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File

Comment: using @mattias's approach I see we could get the original absolute path from the DOM and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 5 / angular 12 I have
`this.file.applicationDirectory+'/www/assets/pdf/my.pdf'`
and it works for my app with
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer.