# Set absolute path as CSS background url property

Tags: android, css, cordova, absolute-path

I can show an image in HTML using this absolute path

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/my.app.id/cache/myImage.jpg
```

as a **src** value.

As [CSS's url property is relative to the location of the CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940451/using-relative-url-in-css-file-what-location-is-it-relative-to) it of course won't know how to interpret the absolute path given above huh?

Is there a way to set the background url property to my given image?

Perhaps converting the given absolute path to relative path of my CSS somehow?

Similar question:

- [PhoneGap on iOS with absolute path URLs for assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073953/phonegap-on-ios-with-absolute-path-urls-for-assets)

Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried just placing the image in a folder inside your assets folder (that is, in a directory one level above where you keep your css in your project folder), and referencing it by "./myImage.jpg"? Unless there's more to it and that's not an option

Comment: There is more to it yeah - image is downloaded and I cannot download it to my project folder ...