# Load assets from www folder on iOS 8 with Cordova 3.7 (file://)

Tags: cordova, ios8

I have an hybrid app that works perfectly on iOS 7 using Cordova 3.7 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.2

I am testing it on iOS 8 and it is broken. 
I am requesting each page(view) of my app using absolute paths, using the `file://` protocol, like:

`file:///var/mobile/Applications/<UUID>/MyApp.app/www/views/add-project.html`

but i get the error:

`Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.`

I read about [this bug](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5839348817723392), is that the problem?

Also, on iOS 8, the location of the www folder is a bit different from iOS 7, it resolves to:

`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<UUID>/MYApp.app/www/views/add-project.html`

Is this correct?

I tried the toURL() and toInternalURL() methods to have the absolute paths like:

`cdvfile://localhost/root/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/<UUID>/MyApp.app/` but I get always the same error.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: why do you use absolute paths? as far as I know, the bug only affects the WKWebView, not the UIWebView, if you are using cordova, it uses the UIWebView

Comment: I am not able to load any file. I am using absolute paths because the application is dynamic with a lot of views created on the fly and navigation is kinda a mess with relative urls.

Comment: I solved it, it is a bug in Cordova, see my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To whoever might find this useful, I finally manage to solve the problem.

The full path to the `www` folder on ios 8+ is:

`file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/<UUID>/<your_app>.app/www/`

but when you request the application directory with Cordova, doing:

`window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory, onSuccess, onError);`

it will give you a wrong path (Cordova 3.7 on iOS 8.1.2) like:

`file:////var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/<UUID>/<your_app>.app/`

using the toURL() method suggested on the docs

Therefore you need to manually do a bit of tweaking

```
var path = fileSystem.toURL();//given by the success callback 

IOS_ASSETS_ABS_PATH = path.replace("file:////", "file:///private/");

IOS_ASSETS_ABS_PATH += "www/";
```

and bingo!

Comment: Why downvoting? Please add the reason for it :/

Comment: The file path that I'm seeing is `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DFE05760-5582-4224-88BA-3BE034C553CF/tmp/myrecording.wav`
by recording an audio file using Cordova Media Plugin.
Your tweak isn't working. What should the *correct* path be for this? Thanks.

Comment: when you record audio, it is saved in the cache folder, not the `www`. Have a look at the file paths on `https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file`. My tweak is for loading html pages using absolute urls, not files. The `www` folder is read-only

Comment: file://private/var/   this pat cannot trigger the webview method 
- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:  how can I fixed it?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and I managed to solve it. In my case, my problem was that every time I update the app, the new app has a different id than the last one. For instance, the path for the older app was:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A3590E8-C78A-4F45-B5B9-51FD0BAFE524/Library/files/file.pdf
```

And new one:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1BC5FS-7B3B-90E8-C7C8-1B7C1984C2A71/Library/files/file.pdf
```

So even though my pdf files were still on the application data storage, I was using the wrong path since the app created a new application id. I solved this by creating a new function that updates my path every time there is an update. I find the application id by using:

```js
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    // Do what you need here
}
```

The filesystem is an object contains the nativeURL inside the root.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

hit a similar problem, adding the WWW worked!

```
pic.style.backgroundImage = "url('../www/images/" + id + ".jpg')";
```