# DocumentViewer not working with Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to work with [ionic/cordova plugin here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer/).

So I put this code in my Page:

```
  showDocument() {
    var options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
      title: 'A book',
      documentView: { closeLabel: '' },
      navigationView: { closeLabel: '' },
      email: { enabled: true },
      print: { enabled: true },
      openWith: { enabled: true },
      bookmarks: { enabled: true },
      search: { enabled: false },
      autoClose: { onPause: false }
    }
    this.docViewer.viewDocument('assets/arabic.pdf', 'application/pdf', options);
  }
```

And a simple button to launch it in the html page:

```
<ion-content>
  <button  ion-button round (click)="showDocument()">
    Read
  </button>
</ion-content>
```

But I can't see anything in the emulator (since it is not possible to run it on the browser)

**Ionic Info is there:**

[image]

**UPDATE**:

This is what I get when debugging with my device and chrome devtools:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**:

I have tried to work with absolute paths but I have got null value, I have made those changes:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
declare let cordova: any;
//staff

pdfSrc: string = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'assets/arabic.pdf';

//staff
console.log(this.pdfSrc);
this.document.viewDocument(this.pdfSrc, 'application/pdf', options)
```

But see what I have got:

[image]

Comment: any errors in the console using [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)?

Comment: actually i have no much idea about remote debugging. I will see how to work with it

Comment: @HoussemBdr  is your click triggerring ?

Comment: Yes, I added an Alert and it worked. Is there may be a problem with my including?

Comment: it says relative urls are not supported..maybe try absolute url? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073953/phonegap-on-ios-with-absolute-path-urls-for-assets

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made me more near to the solution. I tried with absolute paths but I have got null value. See update please

Comment: The new NPE happened because there is no directory created!, BTW if you are reading from assets `assets/arabic.pdf` that's mean your source already compiled with apk so you don't need to get it from `applicationDirectory`.

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim. Do you have any idea how can I fix it then. I'm stack

Comment: @HoussemBdr you may follow this https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer

Comment: @HoussemBdr you should really use the example they provide here: https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer-sample-app/blob/master/www/js/common.js
Also i would suggest you always do all those on ViewDidLoad so you are sure cordova and all the others are properly initialized. If you need more explanation please tell me.

Comment: @ErnestoUlloa thank you, but I didn't also worked, I tried with that example. But don't you see, also, that it is coded in ionic 1 style?

Comment: @HusamBdr did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: No, I let it go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not answer your question directly, but is a workaround for getting PDFs to display.

I had trouble with a lot of plugins for reading PDFs, so I ended up just using a Mozilla project called [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to render the PDF directly in the browser on the Android platform, and on iOS they are displayed natively in the browser. To handle it like a viewer, separately from the rest of my app, I used an [in app browser window](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/).

There are some code examples for PDF.js here:
http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples

Hope that helps someone!